# PHPUnit assertion for authenticated user in Laravel when redirecting from another page

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have redirected the root `/` to the `/login` page as I don't have a root page. I want to make a PHPUnit test pass when a user is authenticated and visit the root `/` page and the assertion should go the `/login` and then `/home` path but I can't make it work.

`web.php`

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect()->route('login');
});
```

`ExampleTest.php`

```php
public function testRedirectShouldBeOnTheHomeWhenLoggedIn()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->make();

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('/');

    $this->assertAuthenticated();
    $response->assertStatus(302);
    $response->assertRedirect('login');
    $response->assertRedirect('home');
}
```

The relevant test fails on the `$response->assertRedirect('home');` even though a user is authenticated. So, the login page should automatically redirect to the `/home`. Not sure what am I missing.

Comment: the redirect route is `login` not `home`. looks good that the later assertion fails, at least on plain sight.

Comment: Yeah, the first redirect point is `/login` and then `/home`. I want to make sure that when the user is authenticated, visiting the `/` redirects to the `/login/` -> `/home`. How do I make such assertion? Got any clue?

Comment: Hmm, when the user is authenticated why should there be a redirect from `/` to `/login/`? Maybe two test cases?

Comment: I just want to make sure the `/login` don't appear for an authenticated user when visited `/`

Comment: Then I might just not understand these specific assertion methods well enough. Sorry.